# C# Parsing Date in "DDMMYYYY" format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, invariantculture

I am trying to parse a string date which is in `DDMMYYYY` format using following code but it is returning false even though `16062001` is a valid date in `DDMMYYYY` format.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("16062001", "DDMMYYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out parsed);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with lower case `d` and `y` as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Eg.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("16062001", "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out parsed);
```

Answer (score 3):

Pattern string is case sensitive. You should use lowercased `dd` and `yyyy`.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("16062001", "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to this document:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Your format should be this one instead:
"ddMMyyyy"

Try changing to this one:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("16062001", "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out parsed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **DD** and **YYYY** to lower case  like below.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("16062001", "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out parsed);
```

Comment: Though a fine answer, it is essentially the same as the other **3**, all answered 6 minutes earlier.